# How i can write MD5 .NEt to rewrite in php

Tags: php, md5

This is the code plz help me out thanks

```
    public static string CalculateMD5Hash(string strInput)
    {
        MD5 md5 = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create();
        byte[] inputBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strInput);
        byte[] hash = md5.ComputeHash(inputBytes);

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < hash.Length; i++)
        {
            sb.Append(hash[i].ToString("x2"));
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: If you want to get md5 in php, you can use `md5()`

Comment: What's the matter with [`md5()`](http://php.net/md5)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [md5()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php)

like

```
<?php
    function CalculateMD5Hash($strInput){
       return md5($strInput);
    }
?>
```

Comment: sir actually i want to authenticate it with the sql server database and the application built in .net when a user registered through .net application the password create as md5 hash and then append x2 to the hash...when i read this password from my php application it cant read coz X2 strign is append to the md5 hash of the .net application so this is problem how i can read this hash usin php...